# Retrieving self ip address when multiple network adapters are in use

Tags: c#, .net, network-programming, ip-address

In the machines my application is to be installed there are multiple network cards, some of them are used to communicate in a inner network and only one of them is used to communicate outward.

Anyone knows how can I retrieve the ip of that specific network adapter in c#?

I've seen a lot of sample on how to retrieve a simple ip adress but with no reference to a machine with multiple adapters.

I should add that this solution must work even when that specific adapter is disconnected from the network and that all adapters are using a static ip address.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        NetworkInterface netif =
            NetworkInterface
           .GetAllNetworkInterfaces()
           .Single(networkInterface => networkInterface.Name.ToLower() =="loopback pseudo-interface 1");


        IPInterfaceProperties properties = netif.GetIPProperties();
        UnicastIPAddressInformationCollection unicastIpAddress = properties.UnicastAddresses;

        Console.Write(netif.Name + ": ");
        Console.WriteLine(unicastIpAddress[1].Address);



        Console.ReadLine();

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: From what I understand the linq expression will return the loopback network interface, and not a real adapter. Are you suggesting I'll relay on the connection name? Unfortunately it not pre-known

Comment: Yes, but it also works with other network adapters, I tested it. Your question was, can I get the IP address of that specific adapter. So, I got the IP address of a specific adapter.

Comment: You can maybe check if the adapter is part of a subnet. Would that solve your problem?

Comment: The goal is to retrive the ip address from an adapter using the given information, if had any more infromation on that specific adapter I whould have stated it.
As for the subnet, are you refering to the subnet-masking of the adapters? if no I dont know what you mean.